# SQL Pivot - take a changing date from column and make it a row header

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a basic query that looks like this.

```
SELECT Database_Name, 
       FilingDate, 
       SUM(ISNULL([column1], 0) + ISNULL(column2], 0) + 
           ISNULL([column3], 0) + ISNULL([column4], 0)) AS Total
FROM  SomeTable(NOLOCK)
GROUP BY Database_Name, 
         FilingDate
ORDER BY Database_Name, 
         FilingDate DESC
```

This query outputs results that look like this.

[image: Table 1]

I would like to take the dates returned in the `FilingDate` column and use them as new column headers with the totals for each database and date being used as the row content. The end result should look like this:

[image: Table 2]

My research suggests that a pivot is the best option but I'm struggling to find the right way to execute it as my dates change each day Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: I'm using SQL Server, I'll add the tag now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is MS SQL, you can use a dynamic pivot table.  Here is a solution using your query (should work, but I don't have the base data to test it).

```
SELECT              Database_Name, 
                           FilingDate, 
                           SUM(   ISNULL(column1 ,0) + 
                                  ISNULL(column2],0) + 
                                  ISNULL([column3],0) + 
                                  ISNULL([column4],0)
                           ) AS Total
INTO #T1
FROM                SomeTable(NOLOCK)
GROUP BY            Database_Name, 
                    FilingDate
DECLARE @PivotColumnHeaders varchar(MAX)
SELECT @PivotColumnHeaders =
  COALESCE(
    @PivotColumnHeaders + ',[' + CAST(UC.FilingDate AS NVARCHAR(10)) + ']',
    '[' + CAST(UC.FilingDate AS NVARCHAR(10)) + ']'
  )
FROM (SELECT FilingDate FROM #T1 GROUP BY FilingDate) UC

DECLARE @PQuery varchar(MAX) = '
SELECT * FROM (SELECT Database_Name, FilingDate, Total FROM #T1 T0) T1
PIVOT (SUM([Total]) FOR FilingDate IN (' + @PivotColumnHeaders + ') ) AS P'
EXECUTE (@PQuery)

DROP TABLE #T1
```

Comment: That's perfect thanks, there were a copy of syntax errors but they were easy to fix.